# How can I have collision detection between array and object so they cannot pass through each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to coding, and especially new to trying to make a game. This is for a class project. Using JavaScript, HTML, and CSS, I am trying to make a game in which, with limited visibility, the user must search for the exit (a white rectangle on the edges of the screen) while avoiding ghosts and interior walls (for the sake of ease of use, the canvas is completely visible so you can see what I am referring to). I am having trouble creating collision detection between the randomly generated interior walls and the player so that the player is unable to pass through these walls.

To be honest I am quite new to all of this, so I do not have a lot of trial and error experience since it is built off of guesses. I was trying to use if statements to detect collision before moving and repeat it for each side (see javascript lines of code 174-199). So essentially using an if statement for each side of the array shape, and if the circle is moving in the direction of collision, they won't be able to move. This hasn't worked though obviously, and I am feeling quite lost as to the correct step to accomplish the desired effect. My code is posted here:

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var startScreen = document.querySelector("#startScreen");
var allGhosts = []
var allWalls = []
var oneDegree = 2 * Math.PI / 360;
var generate = true;
var win = false;
var lose = false;
var o1 = {
  x: w / 2,
  y: h / 2,
  w: w * 2,
  h: h * 2,
  r: w / 6,
  c: 200,
  a: 1,
  distance: 4,
  angle: rand(360),
  changeX: randn(5),
  changeY: randn(5),
}
var o2 = {
  x: rand(w),
  y: rand(h),
  w: rand(50) + 10,
  h: rand(50) + 10,
  r: w / 6,
  c: 200,
  a: 0.75,
  distance: rand(10),
  angle: rand(360),
}
var o3 = {
  x: w / 2,
  y: h / 2,
  r: 10,
  a: 1,
  speed: 7,
}
var o4 = {
  x: w / 2,
  y: h / 2,
  w: w * 2,
  h: h * 2,
  r: w / 1.90,
  c: 200,
  a: 1,
}
var exitLoc = {
  x: parseInt(Math.random() * 2) ? 0 : 1500,
  y: rand(680),
  w: 10,
  h: 50,
}

if (win != true) {
  winScreen.style.display = 'none';
}
if (lose != true) {
  loseScreen.style.display = 'none';
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", ev => {
  if (ev.keyCode === 32 && generate === true) {
    startScreen.style.display = 'none';

    generate = false;


    createGhosts(30, allGhosts);
    createGhosts(50, allWalls);
    setUpCanvas();
    animationLoop();
    document.onkeydown = move;

    function animationLoop() {
      clear();
      extWalls();
      collisionStop(o3);
      collisionStop(o4);
      exit(exitLoc);
      for (var i = 0; i < allGhosts.length; i++) {
        ghosts(allGhosts[i]);
        bounce(allGhosts[i]);
        forward(allGhosts[i]);
        updateData(o1);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < allWalls.length; i++) {
        walls(allWalls[i]);
      }
      // circle(o4);
      player(o3);
      collisionWin(exitLoc, o3);
      collisionLose(o3, allGhosts);
      if (lose != true && win != true) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
      }
    }
  }
})


function collisionWin(obj1, obj2) {
  var differencex = Math.abs(obj1.x - obj2.x);
  var differencey = Math.abs(obj1.y - obj2.y);
  var hdif = Math.sqrt((differencex * differencex) + (differencey * differencey));
  if (hdif < obj1.w + obj2.r) {
    clear();
    rect();
    win = true;
  }
  if (win === true) {
    winScreen.style.display = 'block';
    loseScreen.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

function rect() {
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + h);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
}

function collisionLose(obj, array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (obj != array[i]) {
      collisionGhost(obj, array[i]);
    }
  }
}

function collisionGhost(obj, array) {
  var differencex = Math.abs(obj.x - array.x);
  var differencey = Math.abs(obj.y - array.y);
  var hd = Math.sqrt((differencex * differencex) + (differencey * differencey));
  if (hd < obj.r + array.r) {
    clear();
    rect();
    lose = true;
  }
  if (lose === true) {
    loseScreen.style.display = 'block'
  }
}

function collisionStop(o) {
  if (o.x > w - 50) {
    o.x = w - 50;
  }
  // right of screen
  if (o.x < 15) {
    o.x = 15;
  }
  // left of screen
  if (o.y > h - 50) {
    o.y = h - 50;
  }
  // bottom of screen
  if (o.y < 15) {
    o.y = 15;
  }
  // top of screen
}

function collisionWall(obj, array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (obj != array[i]) {
      collisionIntWall(obj, array[i]);
    }
  }
}

function collisionIntWall(obj, array) {
  if (obj.x + obj.r > array.x - array.w / 2 && move.keyCode == 37) {
    obj.speed = 0
  }
  // right side of obj1 > left side of array AND
  // if(obj.x - obj.r    < array.x + array.w/2 && move() == 39){
  //     obj.speed = 0
  // }   
  // // left side of obj1 < right side of array AND
  // if(obj.y + obj.r    > array.y - array.h/2 && move() == 40){
  //     obj.speed = 0
  // }   
  // // bottom of obj1 > top of array AND
  // if(obj.y - obj.r    < array.y + array.h/2 && move() == 38){
  //     obj.speed = 0
  // }      
  // top of obj1 < bottom of array
}

function createGhosts(num, array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    array.push({
      x: rand(w),
      y: rand(h),
      w: rand(50) + 10,
      h: rand(50) + 10,
      r: 10,
      c: 0,
      a: 1,
      distance: rand(1) + 0.5,
      angle: rand(360),
    })
  }
}

function bounce(o) {
  if (o.x > w) {
    o.x = w - 5;
    o.angle += 180 - 2 * o.angle;
  }
  if (o.x < 0) {
    o.x = 5;
    o.angle += 180 - 2 * o.angle;
  }
  if (o.y > h) {
    o.y = h - 5;
    o.angle += 360 - 2 * o.angle;
  }
  if (o.y < 0) {
    o.y = 5;
    o.angle += 360 - 2 * o.angle;
  }
}

function updateData(o) {
  o.x += o.changeX;
  o.y += o.changeY;
}

function forward(o) {
  var cx;
  var cy;
  cx = o.distance * Math.cos(o.angle * oneDegree);
  cy = o.distance * Math.sin(o.angle * oneDegree);
  o.x += cx;
  o.y += cy;
}

function circle(o) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(o.x, o.y, o.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2000;
  ctx.stroke();
}

function player(o) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(o.x, o.y, o.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();
}

function ghosts(o) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(o.x, o.y, o.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(189, 9, 9)";
  ctx.fill();
}

function walls(o) {
  o.x = o.x - o.w / 2;
  o.y = o.y - o.h / 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(o.x, o.y);
  ctx.lineTo(o.x + o.w, o.y);
  ctx.lineTo(o.x + o.w, o.y + o.h);
  ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y + o.h);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
  ctx.fill();
  o.x = o.x + o.w / 2;
  o.y = o.y + o.h / 2;
}

function exit(o) {
  o.x = o.x - o.w / 2;
  o.y = o.y - o.h / 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(o.x, o.y);
  ctx.lineTo(o.x + o.w, o.y);
  ctx.lineTo(o.x + o.w, o.y + o.h);
  ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y + o.h);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();
  o.x = o.x + o.w / 2;
  o.y = o.y + o.h / 2;
}

function extWalls() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 680);
  ctx.lineTo(1500, 680);
  ctx.lineTo(1500, 0);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.stroke();
}

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
}

function randn(r) {
  var result = Math.random() * r - r / 2;
  return result;
}

function randi(r) {
  var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * r);
  return result;
}

function rand(r) {
  var result = Math.random() * r;
  return result;
}

function setUpCanvas() {
  canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = 1500;
  canvas.height = 680;
}

function move(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    o3.x -= o3.speed;
    o4.x -= o3.speed;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    o3.x += o3.speed;
    o4.x += o3.speed;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    o3.y += o3.speed;
    o4.y += o3.speed;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    o3.y -= o3.speed;
    o4.y -= o3.speed;
  }

}
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  background-color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(189, 9, 9);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Creepster, monospace;
}

h6 {
  color: rgb(189, 9, 9);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Creepster, monospace;
}

p {
  color: rgb(189, 9, 9);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Creepster, monospace;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

#startBox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 64px rgb(189, 9, 9);
  background-color: black;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#startBox h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}

#startBox p {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#winBox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 64px rgb(189, 9, 9);
  background-color: black;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#winBox h1 {
  font-size: 85px;
}

#winBox p {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#loseBox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 64px rgb(189, 9, 9);
  background-color: black;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#loseBox h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}

#loseBox p {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ghost house</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Creepster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="startScreen">
    <div id="startBox">
      <h1>ghost house</h1>
      <p>The lights went out… <br> Your flashlight can only last so long. <br> Find your way out of the haunted house but beware, ghosts haunt these halls. <br><br> They do not take kindly to visitors... <br><br> use the arrow keys to control the player
        and search for a way out. the exit looks like a white rectangle somewhere along the exterior walls of the home. press the spacebar to start</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="winScreen">
    <div id="winBox">
      <h1>congratulations</h1>
      <p>you found your way out of the ghost house <br> refresh the page and try to escape again <br><br><br><br> if you dare</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="loseScreen">
    <div id="loseBox">
      <h1>game over</h1>
      <p>looks like there will be another ghost haunting this house <br> refresh the page and try to escape again <br><br><br><br> if you dare</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>



  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The issue code in question starts from lines 174-199. Thank you for taking the time to read through this and help me out! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right path.  But it does not look like you ever call `collisionWall` in your animation loop so your logic never runs.  Also your logic is referring to `move.keyCode`, but move is a function and you never set a keyCode property on it.  Your logic should look more like:

```js
function collisionIntWall(obj, array) {
  const left = obj.x - obj.r
  const right = obj.x + obj.r
  const top = obj.y - obj.r
  const bottom = obj.y + obj.r

  const wleft = array.x - array.w / 2
  const wright = array.x + array.w / 2
  const wtop = array.y - array.h / 2
  const wbottom = array.y + array.h / 2

  // check if player sides overlap wall sides
  const isHorizontalHit = (left < wright) && (right > wleft)
  // check if player top/bottom overlap wall top/bottom
  const isVerticalHit = (top < wtop) && (bottom > wbottom)

  // if both overlap then it is a collision
  if (isHorizontalHit && isVerticalHit) {
    obj.speed = 0
  }
}
```

PS you will likely discover this collision test is leaving the player partially inside the wall.  when you collide, you likely want to move the object to its previous position and then set speed to 0.

And I'd suggest doing all of the move/collision test logic in *before* rendering in your animation loop.  Structure it something like:

```js
function animationLoop() {
  // game logic first
  moveGhosts()
  movePlayer()
  checkForOutOfBounds()
  checkForWallCollisions() // move player back to previous position if they hit a wall
  checkIfPlayerReachedExit()
  checkIfGhostHitPlayer()

  // render logic
  clear()
  drawEdges()
  drawExit()
  drawWalls()
  drawGhosts()
  drawPlayer()
}
```

this way, you can move the player, move them back, etc in your logic and then render the final result.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your detailed feedback! This is just the help I needed, and I also really appreciate you taking the extra step to help organize the code. Much appreciated, and also really clearly explained, thank you once again! :)